# Ubuntu 21.10 crashes randomly with "read-only filesystem" errors

Tags: ssd, crash, thinkpad, yoga-2

My Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga (20JD) with a Samsung 970 EVO Plus keeps randomly freezing, and eventually shows a black screen with journalctl and other errors. I have to hold the power button to shut it down.
I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.10, if that helps.

Here are some of the errors that it shows (in no particular order, they're all scrolling so fast I can't see it that well)

```
systemd-journald[297]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 757 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
EXT4-fs error: (device nvme0n1p6): __ext4_find_entry:1611: inode #1835133: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0
```

There was also an error in dmesg that appeared right before everything stops working that I can't remember the exact text of, but it was something along the lines of `resetting nvme controller`.

I've already looked at the other posts on this. I've tried:

- disabling fstrim - no change
- using an older kernel version - no vhange
- running fsck - no errors
- adding `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500` to my boot arguments - no change
- updating my SSD firmware - no new versions available
- updating my BIOS - no new versions available

The freezes don't seem to happen as a direct result of any action I take - sometimes it happens within 30 seconds of startup, and sometimes it doesn't happen at all.
Normally the earliest signs start with icons and my cursor changing to blank squares, followed by commands (e.g. `pwd`) returning `bash: pwd: I/O error`. Eventually, my background will dissapear, then GNOME/Wayland/something else important will crash and it'll drop to text mode and start showing the errors described above.
Doing I/O intensive things doesn't seem to trigger it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is my main machine that I do my schoolwork on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Opened up the laptop and the SSD had shaken loose, because the screw holding it had fallen out. Moral of the story: never rule out a physical problem ;)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is multiple complicating factors that make troubleshooting hard.

Boot your linux from an usb stick or such and try zeroing in on the cause that way. I would start with checking the hardware (memtest) and the filesystems (fsck).

Good luck.